# If function and Xlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlookup

I am currently trying to run an excel function that runs the logic that if the cell that has date X is greater than date 2023-01-01 then run an XLookup function. If it is not then do not run it.

Here's what I tried below:

```
=IF(table2!N5>DATE(2023,1,1),XLOOKUP(A2,'Table2'!A:A,'Table2'!B:B),"FALSE")
```

N5 has the date 2022-12-01. The rest is just a standard xlookup function that would run if cell N5 is greater than the date 2023-01-01.

Data for the Xlookup below:

Table 1 : This table provides the lookup value A1.

```
       A             B              C
 1  Position    Classification  Full Name
 2  111111       IT   04        John Smith
```

Table 2 : This table provides the lookup array being A:A and the return array being B:B

```
        A                   B              C                D
1 Employment Position       CC         Valid From        Valid To
2      111111             8888888      2022-10-01       2023-03-31
```

Comment: Don't think it is reading the date, try like this `IF(N5>0+"2023-01-01",XLOOKUP(E3,H:H,J:J),"FALSE"))`

Comment: Are you sure the `J` tag is relevant? I don't see any link with J.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but are you sure that your date fields are dates and not text?

Comment: Have you tried using the Evaluate Formula option on the Formula ribbon to step through the operation of the formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted in comments, I will suggest you use a cell reference, so it becomes more dynamic to use, instead of hard coding within a formula,

[image]

• instead of this

```
=IF(N5>0+"2023-01-01",XLOOKUP(E3,H:H,J:J),"FALSE"))
```

---

• Use a cell reference, let's say cell `A1 = 2023-01-01`

```
=IF(N5>A1,XLOOKUP(E3,H:H,J:J),"FALSE"))
```

So the above helps you in changing the cell A1 values whenever you need instead of bothering the formula each time for a change.

---

Comment: I attempted all examples however it's returns a #N/A, which I believe means the xlookup formula isn't running properly. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show us some copiable data? without seeing any data how could we know what has gone wrong with `XLOOKUP()`, as you have posted the formulas there is no much difference only converting the dates to actual excel dates.

Comment: @AtFirstYouTry can you confirm whether the `lookup_array` & `return_array` have same range of rows?

Comment: I've added some functional data to the original question. I've updated the function be relevant towards that data. My tables live on 2 different sheets . 1 Sheet has Table 1 and the other has table 2. 

As for your question about the rows, yes the lookup array and return array come from the same table

Comment: i found its working, i dont find any error

Comment: It is giving me N/A. I am not sure why it works on your end

Comment: @AtFirstYouTry [Microsoft Documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-n-a-error-a9708411-f82e-4e1b-8a7e-28c28311b993) says it generally happens when it cant find what it’s been asked to look for. So please check what is missing, as for the example given its working

Comment: I got to populate a number however the if function is not being enforced, if I change the date to something that should render false, it does not.

Comment: then those are not dates, those are dates formatted as text, in excel dates are stored as number, trying formatting them to number

Comment: Looks like it works when I do it on a random table i create. I'll investigate why its not working on my source data. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use the `DATE()` function, like this:

```
= IF(A1>DATE(2023,1,1), ...)
```